# PHP MySQL Can't Insert To Text Field

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have this problem that I've never had before, it's really bugging me.

Basically I'm trying to submit text into a text field using a form. For some reason when I submit it with raw text and full-stops only it works fine, however it seems that when there is punctuation like a ' or a ! in the textarea then it just won't submit to the database. No errors are shown but there is just no result.

It's obviously some really obvious problem that I'm missing because I'm dopey, any ideas?

Comment: I think you should probably delete this question (if someone has a real problem with inserting text now they have to read about your spelling mistake, that's not really helpful). Keep Stackoverflow tidy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you escaping the input? See [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: Spelling error :( And this is why I'm not a professional coder.